# How can I get a variable into Silverlight 3 control from my ASP.NET code?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-3.0, parameter-passing

I'm playing with Silverlight 3 at the mo.  I'm trying to get the current user ID into the Silverlight 3 page.  I've done a bit of research and initParams seems to be the right way to go.  Trouble is, they seemed to use the asp:Silverlight control and that's gone in SL3.  I'm stuck trying to get a variable into the initParams list, assuming this is the right way to go.

I've started with a new Silverlight 3 application called "MyFirstSilverlightApp".  I've added a code-behind page to the "MyFirstSilverlightAppTestPage.aspx" to allow me to do any clever bits.

I've managed to hard-code an initParam by adding this to the params of the object defenition:

```
    <param name="initParams" value="userID=id42" />
```

In App.xaml.cs, I've added the following to Application_Startup:

```
    string userID = e.InitParams["userID"];
```

and I've passed that into my page in a parameter in the constructor and then used that in a control.  That all works.

What I can't work out is how to get the value from the variable I created in the code-behind into the param name value definition.  Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick a dirty approach would be to use `<% %>` in the param:-

```
<param name="intiParams" value="userID=<%=myUserID%>" />
```

My prefered solution is to create my own Silverlight Web Control that can render the object tag and its contents in manner taylored to my application.

Comment: Ah, yes, that works.  I'd seen reference to those tags but without the = sign I couldn't get them to work.  Like you said, it feels a bit grubby but it works for this.

I've never written a web control - I tend to dabble in ASP.NET when I have to so I've only done basic stuff.  I don't suppose you could post sample code for such a thing, could you?

Answer (score 0):

Add it to your resources collection.

Try something like.

```
For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In e.InitParams
    Resources.Add(item.Key, item.Value)
Next
```

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't understood my problem.  Either that, or I haven't understood your solution.  e.InitParams is available in Application_Startup, isn't it?  I need to get the parameter into e.InitParams, not from e.InitParams.  I'm trying to inject it into my Silverlight app.

Comment: You're right sorry, I misread your post. this refers to handling the param once it's passed into your app.